# Unknown type name class, did you mean Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I tried to import aurioTouch into my app and I keep getting this error saying

```
"unknown type name 'class' did you mean "Class"?
```

My bridging header file:

```
#import "AudioController.h"
#import "BufferManager.h"
#import "FFTHelper.h"
#import "DCRejectionFilter.h"
```

I tried changing this to .mm for all these files but it doesn't solve my issue. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: go to `Breakpoint` tab on the left side. Then click the `+` button, `Add Exception BreakPoint`, run the project, it will locate in the code line where caused this error. and post it here, so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

To mix C++ and Objective-C you need to use the [.mm extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html). If, however, your class is only C++ (and only includes C/C++ headers) then you can use the normal .cpp extension.

> .mm
>       A source file with this extension can contain C++ code in addition to Objective-C and C code. This extension should be used only if you
>   actually refer to C++ classes or features from your Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I could solve by the following answer: 
[Import aurioTouch Library with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481981/import-auriotouch-library-with-swift/32499476#32499476)

In short, `AudioController.h` is not an Obj-C file because it imports C++ files (BufferManager.h, FFTHelper.h, and DCRejectionFilter.h).  So you cannot bridge it to Swift just like that.

You have to create a pure Obj-C file wrapping `AudioController.h`.