# Unknown Type name 'class'; did you mean Class'? ERROR on CCApplicationProtocol.h, CCApplication.h and Expected ';' after top level declarator ERROR

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, class, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d-x on an iOS game. But I am getting some errors that are preventing the app to compile properly. Here's a screenshot to emphasize the issues:

[image: Unknown Type Name Error]

Any ideas on how to fix those errors? I tried the Xcode suggested methods, like **replacing class with Class**, but this produces even more errors. Whatever Xcode suggested did not work.

[image]

Comment: It is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888951/unknown-type-name-class-did-you-mean-class?rq=1) that you should use `.mm` instead of `.m` when using C++ with Objective-C(++).

Comment: Bo Persson, where to use .mm? I have no .m anywhere in this source?

Comment: It's just a suggestion for things to check. I can see some CDAudioManager.m in the picture though.

Comment: Oh, you say all .m files to become .mm in entire cocos2dx folder? I tried to change CCApplicationProtoco.h to CCApplictionProtocol.mm, but still the Class Issues comes up.

Comment: No. I just hint that there *might* be such a problem with your code. The linked answer says *".mm A source file with this extension can contain C++ code in addition to Objective-C and C code. This extension should be used only if you actually refer to C++ classes or features from your Objective-C code"*. And it seems like you are including C++ headers somewhere.

Comment: Bo, what those C++ headers would look like?

Comment: Maybe because you included header file in Bridging-Header ?

Answer (score 0):

Issues have been solved. I did not touch anything in code. I remember that I recently added few files into the cocos2dx project that was NATIVE iOS code:

1. ProjectFile.h
2. ProjectFile.m
3. ProjectFile.xib

I renamed that **ProjectFile.m** to **ProjectFile.mm** and it compiled without errors! So if you have any Objective C classes added into the project and see that error, try changing .m to .mm as Bo Perssoon suggested. THANKS!