# Import aurioTouch Library with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-audio

I'm trying to convert an Objective-C app to swift.

I'd like to import classes in [aurioTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) to Swift app, so I created the following Bridging-Header file:

```
#import "AudioController.h"
```

but I received following errors in DCRejectionFilter.h, BufferManager.h, FFTHelper.h:

> Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?
>
> Expected ';' after top level declarator

and also in AudioController.h:

> Unknown type name 'BufferManager'
>
> Unknown type name 'DCRejectionFilter'

Of course I use .mm instead of .m, but this does not work.

**update**

The simple swift project just including aurioTouch Library (with Obj-C and C++) is as follows:
https://github.com/pika-shi/aurioTouch-Sample

Comment: Show us your file lists and the files itself please

Comment: @JasonNam I  created and updated simple swift app using aurioTouch Library, thanks.

Comment: I think the bridging header is not working right. Can you confirm that the bridging header is registered in an appropriate way????

Comment: The `Bridging Header` imports `AudioController.h` which is a `C++` file, not an `Objective-C` file. Compilation never reaches the `.m` because it breaks importing, say, `FFTHelper.h`, which is also `C++`. All these must be hidden in `Objective-C++` files (`.mm`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*The present answer shows you how to solve the `Bridging Header` `#import`, and is a step-by-step tutorial on how to create an `Objective-C` wrapper object.*

## .mm does not mean Swift

**.mm does not mean Objective-C either**

It means `Objective-C++`, and merely renaming a file to `.mm` offers no improvement. Notice that you are still including the same `.h` files, and **those** are where the problem starts. These `.h` reference `C++` classes, and they must be wrapped.

**Wrap the C++ in Objective-C**

The file `AudioController.h` is not an `Objective-C` file: it includes `BufferManager.h` which is a `C++` file, and compilation stops right there.

You need to create a true wrapper, say `AudioControllerBridge` which `.h` is in `Objective-C`, and `.mm` can, in turn, make references to `C++`:

**.h**

Absolutely, positively no `C++` allowed, explicit, included, or else.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface AudioControllerBridge : NSObject
    // ...
@end
```

**.mm**

`Objective-C++` tolerates all the `C++` you need, as long as it is not exposed in the interface.

```
#import "AudioControllerBridge.h"
#import "AudioController.h"
@implementation AudioControllerBridge
    // ...
@end
```

Of course, you could simply modify the `AudioController.h` directly, but we will consider this bad practice: for the rest of this answer, we will assume that you are attempting to integrate [aurioTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) **as-is**, with exactly **0 lines**  of code changed.

In the **implementation** of `AudioControllerBridge`, you can now instantiate the `AudioController`, and import all the `C++` files you need for proper compilation, something you could not do in the `.h`. Remember that the `.h` you are exposing to **Swift** in `Briding-Header` must be a pure `Objective-C` interface.

```
// Bridging Header
#import "AudioControllerBridge.h"
```

**ARC**

You will soon see that you need to download [CoreAudio/PublicUtility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Listings/CoreAudio_PublicUtility_CADebugPrintf_h.html) because some files, like `CADebugPrintf` are simply missing from the example, and somehow will not build in your new project, at least in `DEBUG` mode.

If you made it so far, you will then find out that you will get a dozen deprecated warnings, *which you can ignore for now,* and half as much **ARC** errors in `AudioController.mm`. [Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960922/218152) with `-fno-objc-arc` *Compiler Flag*:

[image]

If you made it so far (props), and have added:

- `Accelerate.framework`
- `AudioToolbox.framework`
- `AVFoundation.framework`

to your target in *Build Phases* and compiled, you will find that it builds and links.

**Wrapping it up**

It took me 1h 47mins to reach that point *(proof below)*. The next step is of course to actually put the wrapper code in `AudioControllerBridge`, so that it returns (wraps):

```
BufferManager*          _bufferManager;
DCRejectionFilter*      _dcRejectionFilter;
- (BufferManager*) getBufferManagerInstance;
```

which are the 3 non-`Objective-C` elements in that `class`.

It may be cleaner to to wrap `BufferManager` and `DCRejectionFilter` as well, so that they can be used freely in **Swift**. I will let that decision to the reader.

---

## Demo

Just for the record, all the instructions above lead to a successful compilation of

```
let ac = AudioControllerBridge()
```

as seen in this screenshot. It reveals **all** the files needed, and show a successful build on Xcode 7 for iPhone 6 on iOS 9.

[image: Build Successful]

Comment: Perfect, I was able to use audioController from swift.  Thanks anyway for great help!

Comment: Any chance at all you could share what I missed, and what else needs to be done? Did you create an `AudioControllerBridge` ? Also, thanks for the √: that was a lot of research!

Comment: Your answer is absolutely perfect, and I did anything you said and created `AudioControllerBridge`.  I was really saved :)